# Multiple sites and multiple databases in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

I am a beginner and working on joomla 1.5. I have two question :

1. Does JOOMLA 1.5 support multiple sites within single joomla installation? By multiple I mean each site has its own different contents.
2. Does JOOMLA 1.5 support multiple databases for a single site?

**If above features are supported by any other version of joomla please mention.**

I am very confused by different opinions regarding these questions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shubhra, one of the Joomla! core developers, is looking for others interested in this, as well. Please see Topic:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=199298

Goodluck!
sAmMy